# Joomla.submitbutton('module.apply') makes page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

`Joomla.submitbutton('module.apply')` function makes page reload.I tried it in ajax.But still page is reloading.How can I use this function using ajax with no refresh the page?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your Ajax code you used?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, using the default `Joomla.submitbutton()` as it expressly submits the form, e.g.

```
/**
 * Default function. Usually would be overriden by the component
 */
Joomla.submitbutton = function(pressbutton) {
    Joomla.submitform(pressbutton);
}
```

As you can see the default version above just calls `Joomla.submitform()` which basically submits the form element `adminForm`.

You have to override `Joomla.submitbutton()` in your extension to do the required work, you will also need to handle the AJAX request on the Joomla PHP side as well. How you do that will depend on the version of Joomla you're working with, for example 3.2+ have `com_ajax` [(tutorial)](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) to help you.